# @InjectMocks not working while Autowiring rest of dependencies

Tags: spring, junit, mocking, mockito, autowired

I am trying to test a `ClassA` which uses 2 services. One service needs to be autowired and one to be treated as mocked object instead. Unfortunately mocked object is

> not injected

to my tested class. All fields are behaving like I would only use spring autowiring feauture to set it up. Tested ClassA is inheriting from other abstract class also. If no autowiring is used, mocked object is passed succesfully. Unfortunately I can't mocked ServiceDao, thats why I am trying to combine  `@InjectMocks` and `@Autowiring` annotation.

***Class A.***

```
public ClassA extends AbstractClassA<ClassOne, ClassTwo>{

   @Autowired
   protected ServiceOne serviceOne;      //this services needs to be mocked

   @Override
   protected List<ClassTwo> testedMethod(){
      return serviceOne.getList();      //here method is not returning mocked objects 
   }                                    //as it supposed to do.
     ........
}
```

***AbstractClass***

```
public class AbstractClassA<T1 extends InterfaceOne, T2 extends InterfaceTwo){
    @Autowired
    protected ServiceDAO serviceDAO; //this services needs to be autowired

    protected abstract List<T2> testedMethod();

}
```

***TestClass.***

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:testApplicationContext.xml"})
public class Test {
    @Mock
    private ServiceOne serviceOne; //this mock object and it's return
                                   //objects are set properly


    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private ClassA classA;  //all fields are autowired, including the services that should be mocked

    @Before
    public void setData(){
       Mockito.Annotations.initMocks(this);
       List<ClassTwo> result = Arrays.asList(new ClassA());
       when(serviceOne.testedMethod().thenReturn(result); //here when i invoke mocked object it is returning correct list.  
  }
}
```

Comment: I would not try to mix different injection systems. Instead, simply configure your Spring to create a mocked bean and inject that via Spring.

Comment: could u explain what do u mean about creating mocked bean? How can i tell spring brean to return sth when method invoked?

Comment: Depends what you are using, XML config, JavaConfig, etc. But in all cases you can create a test configuration that simply utilizes Mockito (for example) to create bean that is a mock. Then you can inject that bean itself into your test and tell it what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it's probably best to mock the injected bean via your Spring test context configuration. If you are not able to do that easily, you can using Springs ReflectionTestUtils class to mock individual objects in your service.

In your test configuration XML file you can define a mocked bean:

```
<bean id="serviceOne" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"/>
    <constructor-arg value="com.package.ServiceOne"/>
</bean>
```

In Java side:

```
@Bean
public ServiceOne serviceOne() {
    return mock(ServiceOne.class);
}
```

In your test case you can `@Autowire ServiceOne serviceOne` and use that as your mock object:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:testApplicationContext.xml"})
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceOne serviceOne; 

    @Autowired
    private ClassA classA; 

    @Before
    public void setData(){
       Mockito.Annotations.initMocks(this);
       List<ClassTwo> result = Arrays.asList(new ClassA());
       when(serviceOne.testedMethod()).thenReturn(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: I modified the answer to contain proposed test class

Comment: Unfortunately i don't see correlation between (mockedBean) which is declaread in XML and  usage of it in Test class.

Comment: In your case the mocked bean would be named "serviceOne".

Comment: ok, so almost all is clear but spring is indicating in bean definition that: no matching factory method found in class.

Comment: Exactly, the factory method requires the mocked class as an arg

Comment: it seems yes, but i will test it tomorrow morning. I cant do that now

Comment: This answer provided a quick and clean solution for developers who struggle to get @InjectsMock and Spring Test Runner working together. Worked like a charm. It deserves the upvote.